# Progress bar while method runs ASP.NET MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, progress-bar

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 website that has lots of data entry forms in it. There is a lot going on in the background when a user submits a form that could take upwards of 15 minutes to complete. Is there any way to when they submit a form, to go to another page, and as each method completes, a corresponding progress bar would load?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a number of chained AJAX requests.